# How to identify whether an item inside ZipFile is a directory

Tags: python, file, zip, python-zipfile

Consider a zip file that contains a directory with some files inside, e.g. contents of `sample.zip` are:

```sh
Archive:  ziptest.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  03-28-2022 21:00   ziptest/
        0  03-28-2022 21:00   ziptest/folderA/
        0  03-28-2022 21:00   ziptest/folderB/
        0  03-28-2022 21:00   ziptest/folderA/file1.txt
        0  03-28-2022 21:00   ziptest/folderB/file2.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     5 files
```

How does one distinguish files from directories in Python? (perhaps ignoring [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file))

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

archive = ZipFile("ziptest.zip")
print(archive.namelist())
# ['ziptest/', 'ziptest/folderA/', 'ziptest/folderB/', 'ziptest/folderA/file1.txt', 'ziptest/folderB/file2.txt']
```

One way is to assume that files are the ones that have an extension, but that isn't always the case. I tried wrapping elements of `.namelist()` in `pathlib.Path`, but that doesn't work. Also, one could look at file size to distinguish files, but that will give false signal on empty files.

Is the only way to test for file status is to check if '/' is at the end of the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, Path
archive = ZipFile('ZIP_PATH')
for name in archive.namelist():
    print(Path(root= archive, at= name).is_dir())
```